# PanResponder over a TextInput in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am facing an issue on React-native. I have `TextInput` that takes the whole screen. I would like to change the content of this text input when the user swipes up or down. For this I am using a `PanResponder`.

The problem is that the `PanResponder` steals the focus from the `TextInput`: when I click on the `TextInput`, the keyboard doesn't appear and I can't change its value.

Is there a way to have both the `PanResponder` and the `Textinput` coexist, so that a tap will focus on the `TextInput` and a swipe will still trigger the `PanResponder` callbacks?

I reduced the code to the minimum needed to reproduce the issue:

```
export default class EditNoteScreen extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,
      onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture: () => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={stylesNote.editScreen} {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}>
        <View style={stylesNote.editScreenContent}>
          <TextInput style={stylesNote.editScreenInput}>
            Hello
          </TextInput>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Styles:

```
  editScreen: {
    flex: 1
  },

  editScreenContent: {
    flex: 5
  },

  editScreenInput: {
    flex: 1,
    borderColor: "transparent",
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 10
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah it is possible that `PanResponder` and the `TextInput` to coexist. Your problem is that you are always returning `true` from your panhandlers. Which means that panhandlers gets the focus.

For example one of my projects I wanted `PanResponder` only capture event when moving the finger. But I also had `TouchableOpacity` inside too so `PanResponder` always stole the focus.

To resolve this I modified `onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture` function with custom logic and not to always return `true`. So in your case I do not know what you are doing but all panhandlers get `nativeEvent` and `gestureState` as parameters. So you can for example use them in your custom logic.

Here is an example:

```
onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => Math.abs(gestureState.dy) > 5
```

This means that if the y-axis movement is over 5 pixels only then panresponder will get the focus. Otherwise other elements for example your `TextInput` will get focus.